# Open my eyes so I may see

Tags: bible, prayer, faith, old-testament

> **[2 Kings 6:15-17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Kings%206:15-17&version=KJV)** (KJV)
>   <sup>15</sup> And when the servant of the man of God was risen early, and gone forth, behold, an host compassed the city both with horses and chariots. And his servant said unto him, Alas, my master! how shall we do?
>   <sup>16</sup> And he answered, Fear not: for they that be with us are more than they that be with them.
>   <sup>17</sup> And Elisha prayed, and said, LORD, I pray thee, open his eyes, that he may see. And the LORD opened the eyes of the young man; and he saw: and, behold, the mountain was full of horses and chariots of fire round about Elisha.

Is this the result of the power of Elisha's prayer and/or is it possible that while on this earth, I will ever be able to **see** like this?

Comment: This is the result of God's *answer* to Elisha's prayer...

Comment: I wasn't the -1.  I think this is a reasonable question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two common metaphors used throughout scripture are that we are "blind" and that we are "dead." In both metaphors, the idea is that there are entire worlds and goings-on of which we are unaware.  Paul even combines both metaphors when he describes the Gospel as "veiled to those who are perishing."

Certainly, then, the normal course of events is that we are unaware of this.

That said, the power of the Gospel can be compared to "a blind man receiving back his sight."  This typically doesn't happen until the end, however, for as 1 Cor 13:12 says, "For now we see only a reflection as in a mirror [ed or "as in a glass, darkly"]; then we shall see face to face. Now I know in part; then I shall know fully, even as I am fully known..."

The point is that the supernatural part of Elijah's prayer wasn't that Elisha would see - but rather that he would see NOW as opposed to later.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. However, I still wonder about the "worlds and goings-on"... Does this mean that Elisha was not perishing as he knew God's army was present, and that prior to the prayer (and even after for all I know) the servant was perishing?

Comment: I guess I should ask as well. What does "perishing" mean in this instance?

Comment: to perish is to die.  In this case, we who are in sin are subject to death - thus, as spiritually dead creatures, we are unable to know what is going on...

Comment: Ah thanks, that makes more sense now. In regards to Elisha, he only knew of the presence of God's army but was also unable to see.?.

Comment: @E1Suave: I don't think Elisha knew of the presence of God's army either.

Comment: Perhaps I should not have made this leap, but I had assumed he had some knowledge based on the words in his prayer. "16 And he answered, Fear not: for they that be with us are more than they that be with them.
17 And Elisha prayed, and said, LORD, I pray thee, open his eyes, that he may see. And the LORD opened the eyes of the young man; and he saw: and, behold, the mountain was full of horses and chariots of fire round about Elisha."